# Openlayers 3 Reproject EPSG:4326 vector to EPSG:3857

Tags: vector, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am needing to transform GeoJSON vector data from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857...

***I have a map...***

```
var olMapDiv = document.getElementById('olmap');
            control.map = new ol.Map({
                target: olMapDiv,
                renderer: 'canvas',
                layers: layers,
                interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
                    altShiftDragRotate: false,
                    dragPan: false,
                    rotate: false
                }).extend([new ol.interaction.DragPan({ kinetic: null })]),
                pixelRatio: 1,
                loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
                loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
                view: view
            });
```

***and a view...***

```
var view = new ol.View({
                // make sure the view doesn't go beyond the 22 zoom levels of Google Maps
                maxZoom: 21,
                projection: 'EPSG:3857',
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 0
            });
```

***I define my geoJson Object...***

```
var geoJsonObj = {
                        'type': 'Feature',
                        'geometry': JSON.parse(shape),
                        'name': 'V',
                        'id': V.vID

                    }
```

***I try to read the features into a open layers Vector object and provide projection parameters...***

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
                        features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geoJsonObj, {defaultDataProjection:"EPSG:4326",featureProjection:"EPSG:3857"})
                    });
```

***Then I use the "vectorSource" above in a new Vector layer...***

```
vectors = new ol.layer.Vector({                           
                        title: V.vID,
                        source: vectorSource,
                        id: V.vID,
                        name: 'V',
                        label: response.VList[key].Acres,
                        fill: response.VList[key].Shade,
                        stroke: defaultStrokeHex,
                        style: function (feature, resolution) {
                            var text = resolution * 100000 < 10 ? response.VList[key].Acres : '';

                            if (text != "") {
                                styleCache[text] = [new ol.style.Style({
                                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                        color: '#319FD3',
                                        width: 1
                                    }),
                                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                                        font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
                                        text: text,
                                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                            color: '#000'
                                        }),
                                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                            color: '#fff',
                                            width: 3
                                        })
                                    }),
                                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                        color: rcisWebMapUtilities.convertHex(response.VList[key].Shade, '0.5')
                                    })
                                })];
                            }
                            else if (text == "") {
                                styleCache[text] = [new ol.style.Style({
                                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                        color: rcisWebMapUtilities.convertHex(response.VList[key].Shade, '0.5')
                                    })
                                })
                                ]
                            } return styleCache[text];
                        }


                    });
```

No matter what I do I either see the vector drawn...but in EPSG:4326 or nothing loads...

I've spent way too much time trying to figure out how to get OpenLayers3 to do this...Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use EPSG:4326 in your view then your geojson vector declaration should be

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject, { 
dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
featureProjection:'EPSG:4326' })
});
```

If you use EPSG:3857 in your view use this:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject, { 
dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
featureProjection:'EPSG:3857' })
});
```

Just to explain `dataProjection` is the source coords. Means the epsg of your coordinates within the geojson file. While `featureProjection` is the EPSG of your view and thus the EPSG of your map. Means is the EPSG original coords should be trasformed.

So try to remember this rule: `featureProjection` and `ol.View` projection declaration should be equal.

**Note that I am assuming your geojson coords are projected in EPSG:4326.**

Comment: Great! Thanks for the response and the help!!  Yes, the geojson is projected in EPSG:4326...I have made the edits(**See above**) you suggested in your response and now the map is not loading at all...for instance I don't even see the "ZoomSlider" added.

Comment: No errors? No firebugs? Just not loading??  Would you like to provide a fiddle, so we can figure out what your problem is

Comment: It is working...what I wasn't seeing is that there was another error that was not being thrown that was causing page to load incorrectly...once I resolved the error everything works as expected.  Thanks!!

Comment: I was pretty sure there was a different error. That why I was asking for a fiddle. Glad you find your way out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the brilliant explanation! I spent some time figuring this out and your answer was the one that actually helped me figure this out.